# Should there be a ubuntu-regolith or regolith tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked a question: [How to get stacking layout in Regolith Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559863/how-to-get-stacking-layout-in-regolith-linux) I felt my tagging options were insufficient.

The `ubuntu` tag requests that you only use it if the question is about Ubuntu. Well, kind of? Regolith is an unofficial Ubuntu flavour.  But it's unlikely to be relevant to most Ubuntu users.

If I just tag it `i3`, the WM in Regolith which the question is about, there is a similar problem.  Most users of i3 will not be familiar with the customisations made by Regolith, and it is definitely those that I'm interested in.

Does that mean there should be a specific flag for Regolith?

As I'm not well-versed enough in meta on StackExchange sites, I won't try to create the tag myself.  I'll just say for the record that if there had been a `ubuntu-regolith` or `regolith` tag, I could have tagged my question more specifically and with less hesitation.

Comment: There are today 4 questions mentioning `regolith`. I personally therefore don't think there's a need for a special tag. Using [tag:ubuntu] and [tag:i3] and then specifying more closely in the actual question seems like the best option to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider creating a tag when there's a topic that's sufficiently large to have a community that's using that technology and would search specifically for it. Tags are one way of organizing and distributing questions on the site. There is a maximum of five tags per question, so we shouldn't have a tag for every noun in existence. We should consider a tag when there are people who would ["watch" ("favorite") or "ignore"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) questions with that tag. Short of that, a plain-text search will find posts with that term in it.

You are almost to 300 reputation points, at which [new tags can be created](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> However, note that:
>
> - on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.
> - meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.
>
> Please create new tags responsibly!